# Unable to get the vlookup to work

Tags: vba, excel

I run this set of codes and it returns an error:

Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

I already have one vlookup in another sub routine. 
Is there anything wrong with this code ? I debug and the error appears at the policybox there.

```
Sub LinkPolicyNum()
Dim r As Integer
Dim policynum As Variant
Dim lookup_num As Range
Dim policybox As Variant


    r = ActiveCell.Row
    'Row number of the Selected Cell

    policynum = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 3).Value

    Set lookup_num = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Range("a1:z5000")

    policybox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(policynum, lookup_num, 3, False)
    'to match the policy number to the policy details

    MsgBox policynum
    MsgBox policybox



End Sub
```

Comment: You get this error when the value is not found.

Comment: What wrong with the code ? There is data in the policydetails sheet.  @GSerg

Comment: Then the first column of that data does not contain what you currently have in `policynum`.

Comment: The simplest error control on avoiding that error (the equivalent of #N/A on a worksheet) is to put this one line above it `if cbool(application.countif(lookup_num.columns(1), policynum)) then _` If you wanted to do something more than just skip over it, you could even write an `Else` that sent the error to the immediate window or a msgbox.

Comment: I made a dummy sheet, and copied your code, the code worked fine. Try to copy column "A" from your "PolicyDetails" sheet into Column "C" in your Active sheet, then run the code to test if it works.

Comment: Are the policy numbers stored in the sheet as text... if the value in the cell looks like a number it will be converted to one... then you are vlookup a number to text... try 'Dim policynum As String'.

Comment: @jeeped I never come across such error control line before.

Comment: @Davesexcel i want to take from column C in the policydetails sheet.

Comment: @The_Barman it is all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be nothing wrong with your code.  You are seeing the result of what happens when you use the `WorksheetFunction` version of functions and no result is returned.  Specifically, they throw an error and interrupt execution of the VBA.  In this case, if you tried the same formula in the workbook instead of in VBA, you would get some form of error (`#N/A` or `#VALUE!` possibly).

If you want to prevent this from happening, the easiest thing to do is to change to using `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.  Although there is no Intellisense to help with this function it behaves the same as the other except for error handling.  If the non-`WorksheetFunction` version of a function has an error, it will return the error instead of throwing it.  This allows you to check for an error and then carry on with your code.

If you think you should be finding a value with `VLOOKUP` here then you can start checking for mismatches between text/numbers and other things like that.  I would check with formulas and not in VBA though.

Here is an example of using the other functional form and trapping the error.

```
Sub LinkPolicyNum()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim policynum As Variant
    Dim lookup_num As Range
    Dim policybox As Variant

    r = ActiveCell.Row
    'Row number of the Selected Cell

    policynum = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 3).Value

    Set lookup_num = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Range("a1:z5000")

    policybox = Application.VLookup(policynum, lookup_num, 3, False)
    'to match the policy number to the policy details

    If IsError(policybox) Then
        'possibly do something with the "not found" case
    Else
        MsgBox policynum
        MsgBox policybox
    End If

End Sub
```

Reference on this issue: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/