# Repeat a process

Tags: vba, loops, repeat

I have written a piece of code that produces an invoice statement on an 'Invoice' tab based on a selected Client ID with the data being pulled from the 'Data' tab.

What I would like it to do is produce an invoice statement for each different ClientID.  So the data from my data tab will be split out (by client ID) and put into the statement format, one below the other on the invoice tab.  So to my code I added For Each statement. This loops through all the data fine and groups client IDs up correctly.  However if a client ID has more than one record it reproduces the invoice for the that ClientID as many times as there are records.  i.e. if a client has 3 records, I will get 3 identical invoices.  I only want one.

Below is my code (I've removed a lot of the formatting etc to try and keep it a bit shorter for you to look at) to produce an individual statement, sorry if it's inefficient, I only started vba last Monday and I'm having to learn fast!;

```
Sub CreateStatements()

Dim Selection As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim Client1 As String
Dim ClientRef As Variant
Dim Client As variant
Dim ClientAddr1 As variant
Dim ClientAddr2 As variant
Dim ClientAddr3 As variant
Dim ClientAddr4 As variant
Dim ClientPCode As variant
Dim ClientPhone As variant
Dim ClientFax As variant
Dim Broker As variant
Dim BrokerName As String
Dim BrokerAddr1 As String
Dim BrokerAddr2 As String
Dim BrokerAddr3 As String
Dim BrokerAddr4 As String
Dim BrokerPCode As String
Dim BrokerPhone As String
Dim BrokerFax As String
Dim OurRef As String
Dim StatementDate As Date

Worksheets("Invoice").Activate

Selection = Worksheets("Selections").Range("b6")
Client1 = Worksheets("Selections").Range("c10")

If Selection = "By Client" Then

Dim LastBranch As Long
Worksheets("Branch Invoice").Activate
LastBranch = Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Branch Invoice").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For Each ClientRef In Worksheets("Branch Invoice").Range("B5:B" & LastBranch)

If ClientRef.Value <> "" Then

cl = ClientRef.Value

Worksheets("Invoice").Activate
Client = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 2, False)
ClientAddr1 = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 15, False)
ClientAddr2 = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 16, False)
ClientAddr3 = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 17, False)
ClientAddr4 = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 18, False)
ClientPCode = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 19, False)
ClientPhone = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 20, False)
ClientFax = Application.VLookup(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:AC"), 21, False)

Broker = (Application.Index(Sheets("Data").Range("C:C"), Application.Match(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:I"), 0))) _
& (Application.Index(Sheets("Data").Range("D:D"), Application.Match(cl, Sheets("Data").Range("I:I"), 0)))

BrokerName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 4, False)
BrokerAddr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 5, False)
BrokerAddr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 6, False)
BrokerAddr3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 7, False)
BrokerAddr4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 8, False)
BrokerPCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 9, False)
BrokerPhone = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 10, False)
BrokerFax = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Broker, Sheets("MasterList").Range("E:o"), 11, False)


LastRow = Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("a" & LastRow) = Client
Range("a" & LastRow + 1) = ClientAddr1
Range("a" & LastRow + 2) = ClientAddr2
Range("a" & LastRow + 3) = ClientAddr3
Range("a" & LastRow + 4) = ClientAddr4
Range("a" & LastRow + 5) = ClientPCode
Range("a" & LastRow + 6) = "Phone: " & ClientPhone
Range("a" & LastRow + 7) = "Fax: " & ClientFax
Range("F" & LastRow) = BrokerName
Range("F" & LastRow + 1) = BrokerAddr1
Range("F" & LastRow + 2) = BrokerAddr2
Range("F" & LastRow + 3) = BrokerAddr3
Range("F" & LastRow + 4) = BrokerAddr4
Range("F" & LastRow + 5) = BrokerPCode
Range("F" & LastRow + 6) = "Phone: " & BrokerPhone
Range("F" & LastRow + 7) = "Fax: " & BrokerFax

LastRow = Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 5

Range("A" & LastRow) = "STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT"
Range("A" & LastRow & ":F" & LastRow).Merge
Range("A" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("A" & LastRow + 1) = "Invoice" & vbCrLf & "Date"
Range("B" & LastRow + 1) = "Effective" & vbCrLf & "Date"
Range("C" & LastRow + 1) = "Risk" & vbCrLf & "Reference"
Range("D" & LastRow + 1) = "Transaction" & vbCrLf & "Type"
Range("E" & LastRow + 1) = "Policy" & vbCrLf & "Type"
Range("F" & LastRow + 1) = "Balance Due" & vbCrLf & "£"

'Find All Occurrences

Dim CellPos As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant

CellPos = LastRow + 2
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Branch Invoice")
Set w2 = Sheets("Invoice")
    w1.Activate
For Each rng In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
v = rng.Value

If InStr(v, Clientref) > 0 Then
rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 1)
rng.Offset(0, 2).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 2)
rng.Offset(0, 3).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 3)
rng.Offset(0, 4).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 4)
rng.Offset(0, 5).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 5)
rng.Offset(0, 6).Copy w2.Cells(CellPos, 6)
CellPos = CellPos + 1
End If
Next rng

Worksheets("Invoice").Activate

LastRow2 = Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Range("F" & LastRow2 + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F" & LastRow & ":F" & LastRow2))
Range("F" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

Range("E" & LastRow2 + 1) = "TOTAL DUE"
End if
Next ClientRef
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which line is giving the error?  Add a breakpoint and step through until the error occurs.  Also, can you confirm that it is simply not finding the value?  `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` throws an error when it does not find a value.  `Application.VLookup` does not.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939770/unable-to-get-the-vlookup-to-work/29947049#29947049

Comment: It falls over on the first vlookup and therefore that could well be the problem, however I put in the clause 'if Clientref > 0' to try and cater for that, is that not correct?

Comment: Did you look at that other post and change the method to `Application.VLookup` instead of `WorksheetFunction`?  If so, you should be able to debug and see the value that is returned from that one.  The nice thing is it will return an error instead of throwing a run time error.

Comment: Yes I did, but when I make that change I get the error 'Type Mismatch'... do I need to change something else to avoid this?

Comment: Yea you will have to change the variable to be a `Variant`.  That allows it to hold an error value and a real value depending on output.  You should also add a check for `IsError` before trying to work with the value.

Comment: Ok I've done that now and the vlookups appear to be ok.  However, even after I took out the worksheetfunction part from the match and index functions AND changing dim Broker to Variant I still got a mismatch error again.  Is there something different with this one? (Thank you for your help!)

Comment: What line is the error?  Add a breakpoint and step through until you get the error.

Comment: On this formula (sorry what's a break point?);
    Broker = (Application.Index(Sheets("Data").Range("C:C"), Application.Match(ClientRef, Sheets("Data").Range("I:I"), 0))) _
& (Application.Index(Sheets("Data").Range("D:D"), Application.Match(ClientRef, Sheets("Data").Range("I:I"), 0)))

Comment: Breakpoint is a part of debugging.  Select a line of code and hit `F9` and it will stop there while running and allow you to step through the code and see what it's doing.  In this case, you will do better to split that single line of code into multiple lines for each call to `Index` or `Match`.  Declare a variable for each call and you can see which one is causing the trouble.  It's likely the same issue: one of those is not finding what it's supposed to and is returning an error.  Split it into pieces to find out which one.

Comment: Progress!  Thank you for your help so far.  The code now works all the way through.  It groups clients correctly and produces statements as required, however if a client has more than one record it produces the same number of statements as records.  So if a Client has 3 records, it will produce 3 identical statements.  I guess I need to add something to the For Each statement?